# list.files() for getting files from some of the folders in the directory

Tags: r

I have a folder with many sub-folders and I want the CEL files from some not all.
I have a list of folder names that I want to get the files from but i am not sure where in the code I can call for that list

```
chems =  read.csv("Unique_Chemicals.csv")
```

which contains the folder names I want to get the CEL files from like 
acarbose.Rat.in_vivo.Liver.Repeat

```
allCELPaths = list.files(pattern = ".CEL$", path = getwd(),
                         recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

The code I have will get all the CEL files paths from all chemicals
I have about 140 folders and I want to only get the path for about 77 of them

Comment: Can you show the first few lines of `chem` (e.g. `head(chem)`)?

Comment: Just set a variable as your directories you want, and put that as your path. `dirs <- ("C:/Documents", "C:/R/Foo/Bar")` And `path = dirs`, and remove the recursive, unless you want it recursive in those paths.

Comment: @emilliman5 the chems vectors are in this format acarbose.Rat.in_vivo.Liver.Repeat   which is the folder names i want to get CEL files from

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may get you what you want.

```
dirs <- paste0(getwd(), "/", chems)
allCELPaths = list.files(pattern = ".CEL$", path = dirs , full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks it makes sense but it gives me an empty output!

Comment: please post `head(dirs)` and `head(dir())`